# 404 error when i try to search by category or by tag

Tags: categories, search, tags, 404-error

I have following problem.

When I try to search by tag or by category, I have 404 error. It means that when URL is like "domain.com/category/smt/" or "domain.com/tag/smt/", I have the error.

I tried to edit category's link, but it didn't solve my problem. Changing template also doesn't solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to your permalinks page within the admin to flush the rewrite rules.
Just be navigating to that page will flush the rules, but you could click save even if you made no changes.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress search only handles posts, it doesn't handle taxonomies and their terms ( tags, categories etc )

If you want more advanced search you'll have to use a 3rd party solution